# Subdomains using Apache Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I want to setup Subdomains on my website used for various purpose.
e.g. **rc.mywebsite.com** for Release Candidate, **beta.mywebsite.com** for Beta Candidate and www.mywebsite.com/mywebsite.com for Live version.

I am using Apache 2.2.22 with PHP and mod_rewrite enabled on Ubuntu 12.04LTS Server. In my /etc/apache2/sites-available I have a file mywebsite.com enabled using a2ensite mywebsite.com with entry as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com
    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.com
    ServerName beta.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias beta.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/beta.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts file has

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
XX.XX.XX.XX     myotherwebsite.com
XX.XX.XX.XX     mywebsite.com
XX.XX.XX.XX     beta.mywebsite.com
```

Now the above this is Not working... :( I am only able to access mywebsite.com
When I try to access beta.mywebsite.com I get **Server not found** Error.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Now the above this is Not working... :( I am only able to access mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the question ?

You should get rid of the duplicate ServerAlias, to begin with - it does nothing.

The first-listed vhost is the default; it will receive all requests that do not match any other vhosts.

Other than that, your vhosts look fine; just remember not to use overlapping documentroots.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled NameVirtualHosts in your config? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

> The NameVirtualHost directive is a required directive if you want to configure name-based virtual hosts...
>
> To receive requests on all interfaces, you can use an argument of `*:80`, or, if you are listening on multiple ports and really want the server to respond on all of them with a particular set of virtual hosts, `*`

For example:

`NameVirtualHost *:80`